# Weird relevancy error in mysql full-text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using a query for ordering results by relevancy.

Sometimes it's working:

```
SELECT `baslik` , MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('"konut ev"') as rank 
FROM (`kategoriler`)
WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('+merkez*' in boolean mode)
AND `ozellik` =  0 ORDER BY `rank` desc
```

Results:

```
baslik                          rank desc
Merkez Mahalle Satılık Ev K...  1.43379247188568
Merkez Mahalle Satılık Ev K...  1.43379247188568
Merkez Mahalle Satılık Ev Kon...    1.43379247188568
Merkez Mahalle Kiralık Ev Kon...    1.43379247188568
Merkez Mahalle                  0
Merkez Mahalle Satılık          0
Merkez Mahalle Satılık ...          0
```

But sometimes it's not:

```
SELECT `baslik` , MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('"Satılık ev"') as rank 
FROM (`kategoriler`)
WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('+merkez*' in boolean mode)
AND `ozellik` =  0 ORDER BY `rank` desc
```

Results:

```
 baslik                 rank
Merkez Mahalle          0
Merkez Mahalle Satılık  0
Merkez Mahalle Satılık ...  0
Merkez Mahalle Satılık ...  0
Merkez Mahalle          0
Merkez Mahalle Satılık  0
Merkez Satılık Ev K...  0
```

What can be the cause ? And how to solve that problem ?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kategoriler` (
  `baslik` varchar(200) character set utf8 collate utf8_turkish_ci NOT NULL,
  `id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `kategori` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sayi` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`baslik`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `baslik` (`baslik`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Most probably, `Satılık ev` is in more then 50% of the table.

Comment: Actually first example "konut ev" has more rows then "Satılık ev"

Comment: Well, `ev` is most likely ignored as its < 4 chars, unless you configured MySQL otherwise. What percentage rows contain 'Satilik'? But you could use a boolean search mode for the rank also, saves a lot of hassle.

Comment: Why it's not ignored while it's in "konut ev" ?? no sense to me... And yes ft_min_word_length is the reason of that weird queries, I don't have access for making any changes in mysql. There are 120 rows with "konut ev" and 79 rows with "satılık ev"

Comment: `ev` would also be ignored in `konut ev`, char limit to count is 4 chars unless specified & reindexed otherwise. I am not interested in the total rows. I'm interested in the total **percentage** of rows with 'konut', and the total with 'satılık', no matter the `ev`.  Then again, all troubles could come from the `ı` in `satılık`, which may not be recognized as a word character.

Comment: @Wrikken i don't know how to use boolean search for the rank. can you give me an example query ?

Comment: May I ask what the connection charset is, and the column charset?

Comment: boolean mode: `MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('+konut +ev' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rank`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7468/discussion-between-motto-and-wrikken)

Comment: @Wrikken added table structure. i'm currently using phpmyadmin for testing queries.

Comment: @Wrikken turns out you were right. Using this solved the problem: MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('"konut ev"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this solved the problem as in Wrikken's comment:

> SELECT `baslik` , MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('"Satılık ev"' IN BOOLEAN
>   MODE) as rank  FROM (`kategoriler`) WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST
>   ('+merkez*' in boolean mode) AND `ozellik` =  0 ORDER BY `rank` desc